# How to setBackgroundDrawable without stretching an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

in my Android App I am using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and setting background image of Action Bar in MainActivity:

```
// Custom Action Bar
if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tug));
}
```

Problem is that icon is stretching to the width of the action bar and I don't know how to change it into scaling to the height of the action bar, so that icon will not lose quality.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[Wrong Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY9o3.png)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD5uX.png)

Comment: Could you share with us the expected design?

Comment: Use the proper Image size / resolution of width

Comment: You need to add the image in the proper size and width (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, etc..)

Comment: or else use the 9 patch images.https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: I have added expected image

Comment: Johny - I did. This ic_tug icon is already in drawables folders in proper formats.

Comment: Tomek M, you want a background or an icon in the ActionBar? You say that the icon is stretching. If you want to put an image as an icon on the actionbar don't use the background for it, because background by default will try to stretch the drawable to match the size of the parent view. If you really want an image (not an icon) on the action bar, I sugest to use an ImageView for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ImageView` inside `Toolbar` and set the background as source in the `ImageView`

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Worked great!. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must have your image in different resolutions, and add each different image in the appropriate folder like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the icon in the toolbar, here how  you can do it.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tug);
```

Or you can take an ImageView in your toolbar and add left margin to it and set the image from the Activity.

Answer (score -1):

You can add image to the center of the toolbar using xml layout as below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/yourDrawable"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Worked great!. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but androidcodehunter was first with the answer ;)